# Plugins to be downloaded

Tags: 13.10, plugins

i am new to Ubuntu and have installed 13.10 on my new Lenovo G500 laptop and while i am still exploring the os, my mp3 cds & videos on my mobile are not playing and it says plugin required, but i am unable to download the same. I would like to know whether it automatically downloads when i connect to the internet from the software centre or will i have to manually download the same.

Thanks,
Yadu*

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and in it type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```